# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TingTong.MainWindow.animategrid(string, string, string)'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two classes as shown below

AnimateUtils class:

```
namespace TingTong.View
{
    public class AnimateUtils
    {

        public static void animategrid(string motion, ref DoubleAnimation slide, ref Grid grid, ref Grid grid2, ref Storyboard sbfade, ref Storyboard sbslide)
        {
            if (motion == "away")
            {
                slide.To = 310;
                slide.From = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                slide.To = 0;
                slide.From = 310;
            }

            switch (grid.Name)
            {
                case "GD_Lockscreen":

                    slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400.0));
                    Storyboard.SetTarget(slide, grid);
                    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                    sbfade.Children.Add(slide);
                    sbfade.Begin();
                    if (grid2.Name == "GD_Login")
                    {
                        slide.To = 0;
                        slide.From = 310;
                        slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400.0));
                        Storyboard.SetTarget(slide, grid2);
                        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                        sbslide.Children.Add(slide);
                        sbslide.Begin();
                    }
                    break;
                case "GD_Login":
                    slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400.0));
                    Storyboard.SetTarget(slide, grid);
                    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                    sbfade.Children.Add(slide);
                    sbfade.Begin();
                    if (grid2.Name == "GD_Background")
                    {
                        slide.To = 310;
                        slide.From = 0;
                        slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800.0));
                        Storyboard.SetTarget(slide, grid2);
                        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                        sbslide.Children.Add(slide);
                        sbslide.Begin();
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }



    }
}
}
```

Second class is:

```
namespace TingTong
{

     public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
 static void xmppCon_OnLogin(object sender)
        {

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Logged in to server");


            animategrid("loginscreen", "away", "backgroundimg");  <------error is shown here

        }
```

private void animategrid(string grid, string motion, string withgrid)
          {
            switch (grid)
               {
                case "lockscreen":

```
                AnimateUtils.animategrid(motion, ref slide, ref GD_Lockscreen, ref GD_Login, ref sbfade, ref sbslide);
                break;

            case "loginscreen":

                AnimateUtils.animategrid(motion, ref slide, ref GD_Login, ref GD_Background, ref sbfade, ref sbslide);
                break;
        }


    }

      }
```

}

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error:An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TingTong.MainWindow.animategrid(string, string, string)'   D:\TingTong\TingTong\MainWindow.xaml.cs 400 13  TingTong
```

Comment: `animategrid` **is** static, yet the error message says it isn't. Do you have multiple declarations of `animategrid`?

Comment: yes but arguments are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling like following, since, animategrid(...) method is written inside AnimateUtils class.

```
AnimateUtils.animategrid("loginscreen", "away", "backgroundimg");
```

Also you may need to import 'TingTong.View' namespace on top, if not already imported like below:

```
using TingTong.View;
```

**EDIT**

After taking a close look at the Second Class i.e. MainWindow in TingTong namespace, either you have to change the animategrid() method signature to:

```
private static void animategrid(string grid, string motion, string withgrid)
```

OR

you have to remove 'static' keyword in-front of the event handler: xmppCon_OnLogin(object sender)

You can not call non-static/instance methods from static methods.

Comment: we've got basically the same answer

Comment: @martijn: To correct a litte, we posted same answer almost at same time, since anticipated fix for the problem is same!! :-)

Comment: i still cant access the method animategrid() on xmppCon_OnLogin()...It shows the same error..as the former one..i have used TingTong.view in MainWindow

Comment: Do you see that method in Intellisense? Also what I found is, your animategrid() method has six parameters but you are calling it passing only three parameters and it is not allowed.

Comment: @KathabSp : Please see EDIT in my answer, that should fix your problem.

Comment: @thanks Siva when i removed static from xmppCon_OnLogin() it worked fine...thanks a lot dude..@@@

Answer (score 2):

in the class MainWindow include the reference:

```
 using TingTong.View;
```

functions in MainWindow should be as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    static void xmppCon_OnLogin(object sender) 
    {

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Logged in to server");
        animategrid("loginscreen", "away", "backgroundimg");  
    }

    private void animategrid(string grid, string motion, string withgrid) 
    {
        switch (grid) 
        { 
            case "lockscreen":
               AnimateUtils.animategrid(motion, ref slide, ref GD_Lockscreen, ref GD_Login, ref sbfade, ref sbslide);
               break;
            case "loginscreen":
               AnimateUtils.animategrid(motion, ref slide, ref GD_Login, ref GD_Background, ref sbfade, ref sbslide);
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed **include** to **using** (i've been coding to much vb lately)

Edit2: Added the new function. I missed it before.

Comment: when i changed as you said it shows like this                       Error:No overload for method 'animategrid' takes 3 arguments D:\TingTong\TingTong\MainWindow.xaml.cs 402 13 TingTong